# Custom DaoAuthenticationProvider doesn't send correct exception to custom AuthenticationFailureHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my application, I use Spring Security, and I try to customize it...

I have a custum `DaoAuthenticationProvider` :

```
@Component("authenticationProvider")
public class LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {
    ...
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication pAuthentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(pAuthentication.getName())) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Login is required");
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(pAuthentication.getCredentials().toString())) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(
                    "Password is required");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

And a custum `AuthenticationFailureHandler` :

```
@Component("authenticationFailureHandler")
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler implements
        AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest pRequest,
            HttpServletResponse pResponse,
            AuthenticationException pAuthenticationException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        pAuthenticationException.getMessage(); // -> Bad credentials
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I submit my form **without login** or **with login but no password**, I always get the message *"Bad credentials"* (from `BadCredentialsException`) and not my custom message. Why ?

PS : The exceptions are corerctly throw in my custom `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: Have you checked that hideUserNotFoundExceptions  in AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider is false? You can set it in your custom DaoAuthenticationProvider as it inherits from AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider

Comment: Just did, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

It's like @tobad357 said before, you must set `setHideUserNotFoundExceptions` to false in the `authenticate()` method of the `LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider.class`.